# Is there a way to dynamically edit value in django template?

Tags: python, html, django

Okay so I've been trying to show time in my website, and i was successful in it, but then after the time changes in real-time it does change in the site, we will have to reload the page and then time would b updated. Is there a way to update the time without reloading the page using django templates (html).

Comment: use [ajax](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html)

Comment: is it easy? to integrate with django or python?

Comment: yes it is. read the article or just search about `django ajax` in google or `django ajax jquery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax.  Because ajax can reload specific portion of template without reload whole page.